# Cannot resolve symbol 'default_web_client_id' Error , But App Runs Successfully

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, cannot-find-symbol

[image: Screenshot Image]

I have Tried deleting and re-importing the new google-service.json file. As you can see that there's no error in Build and Logcat , and neither any issue in App after build.

But Red Line is showing under

> default_web_client_id

as

> Cannot resolve symbol 'default_web_client_id'

***Tried Excluding Various META_INF , Migrated to AndroidX , Redownloaded Json File after producing SHA certificate fingerprints and WebKey , Invalidate Caches/Restart.***

**build.graddle (Module-app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "academy.learnprogramming.subjoin"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        packagingOptions
                {
                    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
                    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
                    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
                    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
                    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
                    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
                    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
                    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
                    exclude 'allclasses-frame.html'
                    exclude 'allclasses-noframe.html'
                }


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.graddle (Module-Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Any fix for this yet?

Comment: same problem here, but i can find it in the values generated, but the error persist

Answer (score 0):

after rebuild  **default_web_client_id** not fetched and shown error (but app runs successfully) then

**1.** Apply given dependency in gradle for remove this error :

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.2'
```

***Note:*** Version in dependency may be Change

**2.** Rebuild your Project

```
Build ---> Rebuild
```